# How to change the color of the white across all applications?

Tags: macos, safari, color, web-browser, web-browsing

With the advent of Dark Appearance (System Preferences, General) macOS became more pleasant to use on a dark room. Since Dark Appearance turns dark (or darker) many parts which used to be white (or brighter).

However somethings are still not affected by the Light/Dark appearance control, i.e. this website. It is perhaps outside the boundaries of what the OS can do, I actually don't know.

Is there someway we can tint the white? I would like to do it across all applications.

If that's not possible perhaps I should keep using Light Appearance and reduce screen brightens. That would be and unfortunate solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Websites need to add Dark Mode support themselves. If the browser tries to just flip colors, the result is often ugly at best or unreadable at worst if images are involved. [There's several ways to do that](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/) but the bottom line is that it's up to the website.

That being said, there are Safari extensions that try to add Dark Mode support to existing web pages. Just do a web search for something like `safari dark mode extension macos` to find them.